# How to get sudo insults only through festival?

Tags: command-line, sudo, text-to-speech, festival

I just found out sudo insults, and I would think it would be fun to get those slanders out through [festival](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Festival), but only the insults - how to do that on [Linux](https://manjaro.org/)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using. I assume you are referring to [this festival](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Festival), right?

Answer (score 0):

Insults are simply messages that `sudo` outputs exactly as all the other messages.

You could change [this part of the source code](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/blob/master/plugins/sudoers/auth/sudo_auth.c#L220):

```
#ifdef INSULT
    if (def_insults)
    warning = INSULT;
#endif
```

to something like:

```
#ifdef INSULT
    if (def_insults)
       say(INSULT);
#endif
```

You have to define `say()` of course and decide how to interface with a Text To Speech system of your choice (some are listed [here](https://blends.debian.org/accessibility/tasks/speechsynthesis.fr.html)).

There are other solutions, related to assistive technology. For example running `sudo` on [`yasr`](https://sourceforge.net/p/yasr/git/ci/master/tree/README) and making it only read insults and ignore everything else (you'll have to make them recognizable though).